# Can I calculate the size of HFS Time Machine local snapshots from the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, time-machine

Is there a way to (quickly) find out the size of the HFS filesystem local Time Machine snapshots from the command line?

I can list them

```
$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-104557
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-160009
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-182704
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-203310
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-212838
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-222703
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-14-233021
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-002833
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-012709
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-022703
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-032704
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-042703
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-052703
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-062704
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-072832
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-02-15-082706
```

But I did not find any `tmutil` verb regarding the size.

With `du` I get a lot of errors and it takes a lot of time

```
sudo du -hs  /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/5n/5z9scwyj25b37mkqg3ltgx0m0000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/sq/sb7jrfk14qv7yyh9z55mszp40000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/sq/sb7jrfk14qv7yyh9z55mszp40000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/sq/sb7jrfk14qv7yyh9z55mszp40000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/sq/sb7jrfk14qv7yyh9z55mszp40000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/2f/7t6rd_vd2jnc0twnyb2bltvr0000gp/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/37/__tp_5v96bx012sqphn10wlm0000gr/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/gy/k8z6qc3d4pndcgqrlqjqylrh0000gs/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/gy/k8z6qc3d4pndcgqrlqjqylrh0000gs/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/gy/k8z6qc3d4pndcgqrlqjqylrh0000gs/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/cl/4p6t853n0nd2wmx7q3ljvrnh0000gt/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/cl/4p6t853n0nd2wmx7q3ljvrnh0000gt/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/cl/4p6t853n0nd2wmx7q3ljvrnh0000gt/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
du: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots//Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s MacBook Pro/2018-02-15-002833/Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/cl/4p6t853n0nd2wmx7q3ljvrnh0000gt/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
^C
```

With the GUI (About this Mac > Storage) I get the information in few seconds (so it must be cached somewhere).

I’m looking specifically for the HFS snapshots and not the new APFS based snapshots as they are different entirely. Is this possible on macOS?

Comment: Please be aware that the information about the space used (for local Time Machine backups) displayed in _About this Mac_ (About this Mac > Storage) is not in real time.

Comment: Good news is that Disk Utility in macOS Monterey now shows snapshot sizes

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the "Storage" tab of "About This Mac" from the Apple menu (System Information.app). It should show as one of the colored portions of the bar. The cool thing is, with APFS and its file-and-block level cloning, the answer is probably "not a whole lot". I know it can seem strange. If you haven't experienced this yourself yet: take a big file (5-6GB) and use `cp -c` to copy it 20 times. You won't see a byte more of storage used until you *edit* any of the copies. `du` doesn't look that "deep" (to the level of block allocation), so it will double count everything.

If you have a LOT of very large and very rapidly changing files (like you're editing a feature film or something), where lots of changes are made to very large files multiple times a day, it might be worth disabling local snapshots. But honestly, I wouldn't worry about it unless it's seriously impacting your work or something. Time Machine knows how and when to prune older backups and snapshots to make sure it doesn't overgrow itself.

Answer (score 2):

The info shown in "About this Mac > Storage" isn't exactly showing you the size of all Time Machine snapshots.  It includes other purgeable disk space that's marked that way for other reasons.

I don't know how to find the size of an a particular snapshot, but you can find the combined size of all snapshots of a particular path using the undocumented `sizelocalsnapshotsof` verb on `tmutil`.

```sh
$ sudo tmutil sizelocalsnapshotsof ~/.config
283 KB (282,624 bytes) used by snapshots of '/Users/chris/.config' (126915 total blocks, 69 unique blocks).
```

Notes:

- It undocumented, so be wary.
- If you pass in an invalid path you get an exception and a stack trace. You must pass in a path that's being included in your time machine local snapshots.
- It takes a LONG time to run on large folders, so be prepared for the wait.  You could just run it on `/` and get the combined size of all snapshots, but when I did that it ran for 20 minutes before I just cancelled it and gave up.

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately this no longer seems to work. Eg, `sudo tmutil sizelocalsnapshotsof /Applications/` returns nothing. And many other incantations similar to this result in nothing. I do find it interesting that it offers some help though if run invalidly: https://bit.ly/3vfXni5